# TypeError: Error #1010: web service as3 + wcf

Tags: web-services, api, actionscript-3, flash

I have a simple webservice returning object list of books. I am trying to take this collection with aducentes web service class, but I get the type error:

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

Can  anyone help to pull object into
array and trace the result?

```
import alducente.services.WebService;
import flash.events.*;

var ws:WebService = new WebService();

ws.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connected);
ws.connect("http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TestService/Service1/?wsdl");

ws.cacheResults = true;

var initTime:Number;

function connected(evt:Event):void{
    // var books:Array=ws.IBookService.GetBooks();
    // trace(books[0]);
    var obj:Object=ws.IBookService.GetBooks();

    // var obj:Object=ws.IBookService.GetBooks();
    // trace(obj[0].toString());
}
```

Comment: come on guys all i wanna do is pull object from the web service using alducente. just help me up u can also rewrite a new code . come onnnn

Comment: url works, the method is ok if it wast it used to warn me up.

Comment: no , ws.IBookService.getBooks() is ok i guess if i remove IBookService it says it is not a functioon, if some1 with a alducent code comes here my problem will be solved

Comment: it is still sameTypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

Comment: Then the error is outside of the code you posted. DO install that content debugger player: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of something else...  In the version of WebService I used a while back, you have to specify a `resultHandler` function with each method call:

```
function connected(evt:Event):void{
   ws.IBookService.GetBooks( getBooksResultHandler );
}

function getBooksResultHandler( resultXML : XML ) : void {
    doStuffWith(resultXML);
}
```

The result will be passed to the handler you've passed as a parameter.

Comment: yes i did that in a different function name it didnt change anything thank you

Comment: Without any more code, there's no way to tell. Go get that debugger player. Then post the more elaborate error message you'll get, and possibly your WSDL. Perhaps we can find out then.

Comment: Keep yelling like that and you won't get any more answers.

Comment: In my version it does return XML objects, which you can then pass on: `new WSResult(resultXML);`.